# Boot vhd that is located on external drive

Tags: windows, boot, external-hard-drive, vhd, bcdedit

I followed this article https://www.hanselman.com/blog/less-virtual-more-machine-windows-7-and-the-magic-of-boot-to-vhd, but got error 0xc000000e. External drive is connected through usb 3.0.

Comment: That article is for Windows 7. What is your Windows version?

Comment: Of course windows 7

Comment: Error 0xc000000e means the VHD is not bootable on your computer. We will need to know more about how it was created and what it contains.

Comment: I clicked create a system image in backup and restore , it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup and Restore did not create a bootable VHD.

Use instead the Sysinternals free utility
[Disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)
.